# Creating a web service using console in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services

My employer asked me to create web service using the "Console Template" in Microsoft visual studio c# 2010 express. He said that all i need to do is right-click reference > add reference > under .Net tab add System.ServiceModel and System.IdentityModel.

I am sorry for the very basic question, but I don't know what to do.

Comment: I am not sure if we can really help you with this in an answer. It sounds like you might want to look up some tutorials on Web Services.

Comment: i already did that, im so confused if that is possible. Because obviously when u create a web service application it will run to my default web browser but my employer told me to do it in console :(

Comment: check out my answer. I think he wants you to consume a service from a console application. All what you need is grab a service URL either private or a public one, and then follow my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var wsh = new WebServiceHost(typeof(AService), new Uri("http://0.0.0.0/AService"));
            wsh.Open();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        [ServiceContract]
        public class AService
        {
            [OperationContract, WebGet]
            public int AMethod(int i,int j)
            {
                return i + j;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and navigate to `http://localhost/AService/AMethod?i=1&j=2` in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Actually follow exactly (almost) what he says.

The task is not as intimidating as it sounds. First have the service url (uri) ready.

Then open VS, create a new console application.
Right after the creation, in the solution explorer window on your right, right click on the "references"
On that menu, right there, you have an option to "Add Service Reference" not just a reference.
Once you click that, a dialog will appear in front of you. Input the service URL.
Follow the instructions, most likely all you need now is click OK, to generate a wrapper class to the service.

In other words, you will have class generated by this step, for your service that you can start calling methods on.

something like:

```
MyServiceClient myService = new MyServiceClient();
myService.Method1();
```

Comment: The question is about creating a service... not consuming one.

Comment: what is the difference of that? sorry im not very familiar with c#

Comment: I think I agree with Andrew that you need to pick some tutorial about Web Services in general as a starting point. These videos could be a good starting point: http://channel9.msdn.com/search?term=wcf+tutorial